# SQL SUM amouts by distinct bill's numbers

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I have this query:

```
SELECT companys.name as pav, SUM(distinct bills.amout) - SUM(cheques.amount)AS 
amount FROM companys INNER JOIN bills ON companys.id   = bills.company LEFT  JOIN 
cheques ON bills.bill_nr = cheques.bill_nr GROUP BY companys.name
```

For example if I have 2 bills with amounts (1000 and 1000) and 2 cheques for first bill (100 and 200) and for second 1 cheque (800), I get result -100 instead of 900. This happens because it sums bill amount 1000 only one time because they are same, but I need to sum them of distinct bills.bill.nr. How to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the checks are multiplying the billed amounts.  A good solution is to aggregate everything *before* the join, so the numbers are all correct:

```
SELECT c.name as pav, (bamount - COALESCE(chamount, 0)) AS amount
FROM companys c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT b.company, SUM(b.amount) as bamount
      FROM bills b
      GROUP BY b.company
     ) b
     ON c.id = b.company LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.company, SUM(ch.amount) as chamount
      FROM bills b JOIN
           cheques ch
           ON b.bill_nr = ch.bill_nr
      GROUP BY b.company
     ) ch
     ON c.id = ch.company;
```

Notice that I added a `COALESCE()` so missing checks will not result in `NULL` values.